# AnnotationConfigApplicationContext has not been refreshed yet - what's wrong?

Tags: java, spring, configuration

My very basic spring application stopped working and I can't understand what's happened.
**pom.xml:**

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Config class:**

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

@Bean
public HelloWorld helloWorld() {
         return new HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

**Bean class:**

```
public class HelloWorld {
    private String message;

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
         return message;
    }
}
```

**Entry point of application:**

```
public class MainApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(MyConfig.class);
    HelloWorld bean = ctx.getBean(HelloWorld.class);
    bean.setMessage("ladjfaj");
    System.out.println(bean.getMessage());
}
}
```

And I'm getting an error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6ebf8cf5 has not been refreshed yet
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.assertBeanFactoryActive(AbstractApplicationContext.java:943)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:967)
>       at com.nikolas.config.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:12)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to call `ctx.refresh()` before you can call `ctx.getBean(HelloWorld.class);`

Comment: Thanks, it works! Is it necessary to call **ctx.registerShutdownHook();** for proper schutdown the container?

Comment: @Nikolas I do not think so.

Comment: This link can be useful https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html#register-java.lang.Class...-

Answer (score 17):

If you dont want to call `ctx.refresh()` explicitly, just initialize ApplicationContext like this: 
`new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class)`, then configuration will be registered and refreshed implicitly

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone has a similar issue and can´t relate directly to the example above, this may help:

I ran into the problem when I had one of my repositories outside of the folder that was included in

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.myproject.repositores"})
```

Which lead to this first exception:

> Description:  Field profileRepository in
> com.myproject.featurepackage.config.ProfileService required a bean of
> type 'com.myproject.featurepackage.ProfileRepository' that could not
> be found.  The injection point has the following annotations:     -
> @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

When I **afterwards accessed the ApplicationContext to instanciate a bean**, I ran into the error

> org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4983159f
> has not been refreshed yet